# formCollection doesn't Capture list box component from view

Tags: javascript, c#, formcollection

I have a view with the following code wrapping inside a form tag:

```
     <select name="@SchoolSystemMVCRazor.Models.Miscellaneous.Helpers.RazorHelper.ReportCardSubjectSequence.Selector1" id="@SchoolSystemMVCRazor.Models.Miscellaneous.Helpers.RazorHelper.ReportCardSubjectSequence.Selector1" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px;height: 100px">
                                                                                    @foreach (SchoolSystemMVCRazor.Models.General.Subject subject in leftSubjects)
        {
            <option value="@subject.SubjectId">@subject.DisplayName</option>
        }
        </select>
    <input type="button" style="width: 300px" id="toRight" value=">" />

    <select name="@SchoolSystemMVCRazor.Models.Miscellaneous.Helpers.RazorHelper.ReportCardSubjectSequence.Selector2" id="@SchoolSystemMVCRazor.Models.Miscellaneous.Helpers.RazorHelper.ReportCardSubjectSequence.Selector2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px;height: 100px">
@foreach (SchoolSystemMVCRazor.Models.General.Subject subject in rightSortedSubjects)
    {
    <option value="@subject.SubjectId">@subject.DisplayName</option>
    }
    </select>
    <input type="button" style="width: 300px" id="toLeft" value="<" />



<script>
    $(function() {
        function moveItems(origin, destination) {
            $(origin).find(':selected').appendTo(destination);
        }
        $('#toLeft').on('click', function() {
            moveItems('#@SchoolSystemMVCRazor.Models.Miscellaneous.Helpers.RazorHelper.ReportCardSubjectSequence.Selector2', '#@SchoolSystemMVCRazor.Models.Miscellaneous.Helpers.RazorHelper.ReportCardSubjectSequence.Selector1');
        });
        $('#toRight').on('click', function() {
            moveItems('#@SchoolSystemMVCRazor.Models.Miscellaneous.Helpers.RazorHelper.ReportCardSubjectSequence.Selector1', '#@SchoolSystemMVCRazor.Models.Miscellaneous.Helpers.RazorHelper.ReportCardSubjectSequence.Selector2');
        });
        $('#toLeftAll').on('click', function() {
            moveAllItems('#@SchoolSystemMVCRazor.Models.Miscellaneous.Helpers.RazorHelper.ReportCardSubjectSequence.Selector2', '#@SchoolSystemMVCRazor.Models.Miscellaneous.Helpers.RazorHelper.ReportCardSubjectSequence.Selector1');
        });
        $('#toRightAll').on('click', function() {
            moveAllItems('#@SchoolSystemMVCRazor.Models.Miscellaneous.Helpers.RazorHelper.ReportCardSubjectSequence.Selector1', '#@SchoolSystemMVCRazor.Models.Miscellaneous.Helpers.RazorHelper.ReportCardSubjectSequence.Selector2');
        });
    });
</script>
```

[The view of the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T57PW.png)

Everything seem working until i do something like clicking the item on the selector2 (right) and move it to the left. Now the formCollection in my C# script only capture selector1. The selector2 value is important for me because I need to extract the user-selected values on the selector2 by the sequence they were added.

[Debugging show only selector1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbrxp.png)

I wonder what did I do wrong in terms of coding causing the selector2 doesn't get captured in formCollection? Any javaScript or C# expert can help as I don't know what gone wrong as I am new in web development?

Comment: Hi, anyone know why the selector2 object doesn't get extracted into formCollection?

Comment: Anybody knows why the selector2 is not included in FormCollection? Provided that the object is named with a name and wrapped inside a form tag. Any small detail I missed out?